# current path didnt match in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

i want get my album.object.all() coding running in my web site. i have included data but after putting it in urls.py file it doesnt find the path to response. please help me.

this is django 1.11.2

my `urls.py` file

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from myapp import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^album/?$', views.music, name='music'),
        url(r'^album/(?P<album_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
        url(r'^Database/?$', views.Database, name='Database'),
    ]
```

my `views.py` file

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from myapp.models import Album


    # Create your views here.
    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    def music(request):
        all_albums = Album.objects.all()
        context ={'all_albums': all_albums,}
        return render(request, 'album.html', context)

    def detail(request, album_id):
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for album id: " + str(album_id) + "</h2>")

    def Database(request):
        return render(request, 'data.html')
```

my `model.py` page

```
    from django.db import models

    class Album(models.Model):
        artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.album_title+ ' - ' +self.artist

    class Song(models.Model):
        Album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #any songs of the related to the deleted album will be deleted
        file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        song_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

want to use it get the whole directory by `<pk>=album_id`

Comment: What URL are you going to in your browser. It's easier to help if you include the full error message in your question.

Comment: Have a look at Django's generic views. I think they will help you in this situation. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^$ [name='home']
^album/?$ [name='music']
^album/(?P<album_id>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^Database/?$ [name='Database']
The current path, myapp/, didn't match any of these

Comment: The error shows you have tried to go to `http://localhost:8000/myapp/` in your browser, but you don't mention `myapp` anywhere in the `urls.py` you have shown. Try going to `http://localhost:8000/album/`.

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, it may get you to add something like `url('myapp', include('myapp.urls'))`, then put `url(r'^album/?$', views.music, name='music'),` inside the app's urls, `myapp/urls.py`. If you do this, be very careful that you are putting the correct code in the correct files.